# Kubernetes service vs Load balancer

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, kubernetes

A service in kubernetes is a object representation that is used by kube-proxy to link the VIP of the service to one of the containers behind the service. This can be done by several kube-proxy modes that each has different load distribute patterns. All this smells a lot like a load balancer. But this is done on all service types.

What differentiates the raw distribution made by the proxy and a load balancer?

I myself has concluded the following:

1. Sole purpose of the service is to provide a stable VIP
2. Load distribution done by the kube-proxy smells like a very simple load balancer, but it is done ON the node. And the job 5o be executed by this entity actually lies in the name: kube-proxy. It is a proxy.
3. An external load balancer has only one job, to balance the load. The resources (RAM and CPU) used here is devoted to this and nothing else.

Am I on the right track here or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track as a true load balancer would keep a check on the load of nodes and accordingly balance the load but to the best of my little knowledge, I know that the Kube simple load balancer just does round-robin load balancing irrespective of load metrics!